# Reload only new records without having a flag for a new entry.

Tags: .net, sql-server, diff

There is a table in database with 3 columns [StringColumn], [FloatColumn1], [FloatColumn2]. 
All rows in this table are distinct, no duplicates.

It has about 1M records, every day it receives about 10-50 new records.

On the client side when application starts it downloads ALL the records from this table (for look-up fields) via a web-service call, that's about 85Mb which is pretty bad.

What would be the best way to get only the differences between a local cache of data and the database?

If I'd have a timestamp column when record was created then it would be pretty easy, but having only those 3 columns I'm not sure what would be the best way.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Can you create a trigger that dumps the new data in to another table.  Then you could get the data from that table instead?  Of course, you would want to clear out that table after synchronizing the data each day.

Comment: Does that existing data mutate?

Comment: can't create a trigger, don't have access to database. but I like the idea, I'll have to check with our DBA. No, the existing data doesn't mutate.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really cannot edit the DDL in any way (table schema, triggers, etc), your goal should be to limit data transfer (which you seem to realize, citing the 85Mb number).

One way to do this is to do range queries before comparing full sets of data.

For example, in your code you know the number of records with [FloatColumn1] between 0.0 and 19.999, 20.0 and 29.999 etc. It would be trivial to ask SQL Server if it has the same number of records within each range. For ranges that have a different count, you can refine the search until you can quickly do a full comparison within that range (experimentation and benchmarking is the best way to determine the optimal minimum range size). You also have the option of using the same idea on combinations of the other columns (another choice that depends on your data).

With LINQ, code implementing the above shouldn't look too ugly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a second table that you flush daily is a client may not have flushed.

If the data does not mutate then a simple Identity column.

The client just grabs data > the max identity at the client.

Comment: I would assume that the client would cause the flush after the data was successfully downloaded and merged with local data.

Comment: I am assuming more than 1 client. Used the term client side that led me to believe more than one client.

Comment: Then I think this is the simple and efficient solution.